# Can I use libraries published under MPL 2.0 and MIT in a project that uses APL 2.0?

Tags: licensing, legal, mit-license, apache-license

I want to use two particular open-source libraries, in unmodified form, as dependencies of a project.  One of the libraries is published under the MIT license; the other library is published under the Mozilla Public License version 2.0.  The project itself is licensed under the Apache Public License version 2.0.

Can I legally use the two libraries without changing the project's license?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of the MPL, MIT or Apache licenses are viral. This means that none of the licenses tries to extend its reach beyond the files that it is explicitly applied to.

Additionally, all three of the licenses are permissive in nature, so they allow the code to be included in other projects with only few restrictions.

Combined, this means that your project can include libraries with a mixture of these licenses without any problem and none of the libraries would put any constraints on the license that you choose for your own code.